# Is there a way to add an example for plain text content type in OpenAPI?

Tags: openapi

Using OpenAPI 3.x.x, is there a way to add an example of request body that accepts plain text format?

```yaml
/path/to/api/:
  ... more properties
  requestBody:
    required: true
    content:
      text/plain:
        schema:
          $ref: '...path/to/schema'
        example:
          value:
```

I need to add example of a string input "hello", but it expects a JSON object.

Answer (score 3):

The OAS 3.x.x `Example` schema indicates the `value` property accepts any JSON Schema primitive value since constraints are undefined. This can be interpreted as `type: ["object", "array", "boolean", "string", "number", "integer", null]`

The recommended keyword for the latest version of OAS is `examples` vs `example`.

```yaml
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/schemas/v3.0/schema.yaml#L394-L417

MediaType:
    type: object
    properties:
      schema:
        oneOf:
          - $ref: '#/definitions/Schema'
          - $ref: '#/definitions/Reference'
      example: {}
      examples:
        type: object
        additionalProperties:
          oneOf:
            - $ref: '#/definitions/Example'
            - $ref: '#/definitions/Reference'
      encoding:
        type: object
        additionalProperties:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Encoding'
    patternProperties:
      '^x-': {}
    additionalProperties: false
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/ExampleXORExamples'
Example:
    type: object
    properties:
      summary:
        type: string
      description:
        type: string
      value: {}
      externalValue:
        type: string
        format: uri-reference
    patternProperties:
      '^x-': {}
    additionalProperties: false
```

The `schema` for `text/plain` can be only described as `type: string`, not a schema object. Using a `$ref` would only be viable if the referenced schema was defined as a `type: string`.
Thus, the `value` for a text/plain request can be defined as a `string` value.

```yaml
content:
    text/plain
      schema:
        type: string
      examples:
        test_request:
          value: "hello"
```